# Краш при вызове функции

Tags: c++, xor

я хочу обфусцировать свой код и сделал отдельный синглтон для ксора адресов переменных. При вызове ксора ключей происходит краш: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00A310AF в ConsoleApplication6.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x40003D6C. Прощу помощь, код ниже.
UPD: Да, очень важно, чтобы функция Xor( ) возвращала указатель, а g_XorClass не был им.

Код синглтона:

```
template< typename T>
class CXorPtr
{
private:
    uint64_t m_XorKey1 = uint64_t();
    uint64_t m_XorKey2 = uint64_t();
protected:
    CXorPtr()
    {
        m_XorKey1 = RandomHash();
        m_XorKey2 = m_XorKey1 ^ (uint64_t)this;
    }
public:
    __forceinline T& Xor()
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_XorKey1 ^ m_XorKey2);
    }
};
```

Код класса, наследующего ксор:

```
class C_XorClass : public CXorPtr < C_XorClass* >
{
public:
    virtual void PrintAText( const char* strString )
    {
        std::cout << strString << std::endl;
    }
};

C_XorClass g_XorClass;
```

Вся шаманская магия:

```
int main( )
{
    g_XorClass.Xor( )->PrintAText( "hello from xored pointer" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А если (в целях отладки) не ксорить, а просто запомнить в конструкторе в `m_XorKey2` значение  `this`, а из `.Xor()` вернуть `return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_XorKey2);`, то не упадет?

Comment: Ответ на предыдущий коммент: падает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В этом примере при обфускации указателя используется указатель на `CXorPtr<T>`, а при деобфускации - указатель на `T`. Однако эти указатели не обладают свойством pointer-interconvertible. Соответственно и результат кривой.

Comment: Уже исправил, не обязательно было делать именно указатель. Появилась немного другая и не менее серьезная проблема: Конструктор класса CXorPtr остается в памяти и позволяет вычислить алгоритм генерации ключей. Вы случайно не знаете способ стирания конструктора?

Comment: @Porches Честно говоря, этот алгоритм совершенно не важен, так как ключ лежит в памяти радом с обфусцированным указателем. И вся эта обфускация выглядит, как пустая трата времени.

Comment: Да, но по крайней мере это затрудняет жизнь реверсерам, так как для начала им нужно будет посчитать выражение или написать скрипт для автоматизации этого. Не могли бы вы помочь с удалением конструктора?

Comment: @Porches Скорее это вы себе ее затрудняете, а реверсеров еще надо как-то заинтересовать... С удалением конструктора тут вряд ли что-то посоветую.